# Sumar toda la tabla de la base de datos y mostrarla con el total

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Me gustaría sumar todos los datos guardados en mi tabla precio, esta tabla precio (money) guarda el precio de unas pizzas (es un programa de venta de pizzas) cada pizza tiene un precio de 10€, me gustaría sumarla y enseñar el precio final en un MessageBox.show().

Por ahora he intentado hacerlo así

```
SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("server=JAUMEVIVES\\SQLEXPRESS; database=Proyecto; Integrated Security = SSPI");
         SqlCommand comandosql = new SqlCommand();
         conexion.Open();
         comandosql.Connection = conexion;
         comandosql.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(Precio) FROM Pizzas";
        SqlDataReader midatareader = comandosql.ExecuteReader();
        string precio;
        precio = midatareader["Precio"].ToString();

        MessageBox.Show("Su precio total es"+precio);
```

Muchas gracias de antemano, si hay algo que necesiten pregunten, estoy aprendiendo solo y me cuesta un poco, no sean duros conmigo :)

Comment: Por un lado, deberías poner que problema tienes con el código que muestras. Por otro, si lo único que hace tu consulta es devolver un valor, en lugar de `ExecuteReader` usa `ExecuteScalar`

Comment: El fallo es que no se como mostrar la suma de todos los precios, creo que la sentencia Sql esta bien, pero lo otro lo dudo mucho.

Comment: Quiero mostrar los datos que me da esa sentencia Sql por un message.box

Comment: Pero has probado ese código? Te da algun error, no te muestra los resultados esperados? Trata siempre de dar cuanta mas información mejor :

Comment: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Precio este es el error que me da

Comment: En la consulta SQL después de `SUM(Precio)` añade `AS Precio`. Ya que ahora mismo tal y como tienes la SQL, el nombre del campo sería algo tal que: `SUM(Precio)` Por tanto, cuando luego con: `precio = midatareader["Precio"].ToString();` no encontrará nada

Comment: Me dice que error de lectura porque no hay datos

Comment: @ElBarto añade manualmente algún resultado para que puedas hacer pruebas, te está indicando que la tabla `Pizzas` está vacía.

Comment: Porque no has leido nada todavía. Añade `midatareader.Read()` antes de tratar de acceder a "Precio". De todas maneras, como te he dicho, para este caso debes usar `ExecuteScalar` en lugar de un `SqlDataReader`

Comment: he puesto la aplicación que estoy haciendo para mostrar que si que tiene algo en la base de datos

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @Pikoh solo tenia que poner lo de midatareader.Read() antes de precio y ya esta

Comment: @ElBarto me alegró que hayas podido solucionarlo, sin embargo, como dice Pikoh arriba, utiliza `ExecuteScalar` si vas a obtener solo un resultado en tu consulta.

Comment: SUM(Precio*cantidad) as total